# How can i find and replace matching url on page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have need to find and replace all link that match for example i am looking for

`.domainname.com/Home` and i want to replace it with `.domainname.com/` i only want to remove part of link

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    aHref = $this.attr('href'); //get the value of an attribute 'href'
  $this.attr('href', aHref.replace('domainname.com/Home', 'domainname.com/')); //set the value of an attribute 'href'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="https://domainname.com/Home">
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>


  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://domainname.com/about-us">
      <span>About Us</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://domainname.com/contact-us">
      <span>Contact Us</span>
    </a>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried to so far?  `.replace`?  `.attr("href")`?

Comment: If you answered your own question feel free to post an answer here below instead of an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `URL` api

```js
function changeURL(){
  let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
  Object.values(links).forEach(link=>{
    let url = new URL(link.href)
    if(url.pathname === '/Home'){
      link.href = url.origin
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="https://domainname.com/Home">
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://domainname.com/about-us">
      <span>About Us</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://domainname.com/contact-us">
      <span>Contact Us</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="changeURL()">Change urls</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining

- [[name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- [.attr( attributeName, function )](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

I would suggest:

```js
$('[href*="domainname.com/Home"]').attr('href', 
             (i, attr) => attr.replace(/domainname.com\/Home/g, 'domainname.com/'));

console.log($('li:first').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="https://domainname.com/Home">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://domainname.com/about-us">
            <span>About Us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://domainname.com/contact-us">
            <span>Contact Us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you selected also jquery tag.. then here:
    https://codepen.io/guymevents/pen/jONMeoL

```
$("a").each((i,item) => {
    var jItem = $(item)
    jItem.prop("href", 
        jItem.prop("href").replace(/domainname.com\/Home/,'domainname.com')
    )
})
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but seems incomplete or was just copied from somewhere without updating for OPs requirement (to *change* the url)

Comment: I did downvote because this example doesn't fit OP's question

Comment: @LaurentS. ok, then i changed the example :)

Comment: So the OP asks for replacing ".domainname.com/Home" by ".domainname.com/", and you propose a solution replacing actually nothing by "guy". I don't see any good in that and your edition makes no further step towards a correct answer

Comment: @LaurentS. Thank you for your feedback. now i understand why you voted down.